# Xamarin IOS build error in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I try to build an old Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017 but fail with the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to resolve assembly: 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve(TypeReference self)
   at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeEnum(TypeReference enum_type)
   at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElementValue(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElement(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeFixedArgument(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeConstructorArguments(CustomAttribute attribute, Collection`1 parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader.ReadCustomAttributeSignature(CustomAttribute attribute)
   at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.<Resolve>b__2(CustomAttribute attribute, MetadataReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet](TItem item, Func`3 read)
   at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.Resolve()
   at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.get_ConstructorArguments()
   at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
   at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadMethods(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadTypes(Collection`1 types)
   at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadModule(ModuleDefinition module)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo(ModuleDefinition module, Stream stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(Stream stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildiOSResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, List`1 resourceItems)
```

[image]

The reference for Xamarin.IOS looks OK in the project, and is pointing to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Xamarin.iOS.dll
```

And the project is working on a team members computer but not mine. So I guess it has something to do with versioning.

[image]

Some tips?

Comment: Any nuget may be missing on your computer

Comment: Added image showing references. Xamarin.iOS is not linked from a nuget package.

Comment: there should be warning when you build your project. That's the reason of this error, can you show warning list too

Comment: Sure, added an image of 2 warnings and the error mentioned above.

Comment: you should solve second warning about displayalert, lets try to search for solution

Comment: Basic solution is rename your custom displayalert wrapper to CustomDisplayAlert or something else

Comment: It's just a warning so it should not affect the build of this project. But I fixed it anyway and the build error is still there.

Comment: Try changing iOS Project Options > iOS Build > Linker Behavior to "Don't Link"

Comment: Unfortunately there was no difference after changing that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that my old Xamarin.iOS project was referencing the Xamarin.Build.Download nuget package with version 0.4.2.
Updating to version 0.4.7 (current at time of this post) and then rebuilding the entire solution solved the issue for me.